# Optimal Maximum distance traveled problem

Tags: c#

Given a maximum travel distance (forward and backwards roads), return the route which uses the maximum travel distance, in case of multiple same routes which uses the maximum travel distance return multiple routes.

**Example 1**

- Forward route : `[[1,3000],[2,5000],[3,4000],[4,10000],[5,8000]]`
- Backward route : `[[1,1000],[2,3000],[3,4000]]`
- **Max Distance Traveled**: `11000`

Result must be: `[4,1]` and `[5,2]`, as the total traveled distance is `11000` which is less than or equal to max distance.

**Example 2**

- Forward route : `[[1,3000],[2,5000],[3,4000],[4,10000]]`
- Backward route : `[[1,2000],[2,3000],[3,4000]]`
- **Max Distance Traveled**: `11000`

Result must be: `[2,3]`, as the total traveled distance is `9000` which is less than or equal to max distance.

I was able to solve this in **O(forLength * backLength)** like the below code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    int[][] f = new int[5][];
    int[][] b = new int[3][];

    f[0] = new int[] { 1, 3000 };
    f[1] = new int[] { 2, 5000 };
    f[2] = new int[] { 3, 4000 };
    f[3] = new int[] { 4, 10000 };
    f[4] = new int[] { 5, 8000 };

    b[0] = new int[] { 1, 1000 };
    b[1] = new int[] { 2, 3000 };
    b[2] = new int[] { 3, 4000 };

    var result = sol(f, b, 11000);
}

public static List<List<int>> sol(int[][] f, int[][] b,int max) {
    List<List<int>> li = new List<List<int>>();
    int m = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++) {
            if (f[i][1] + b[j][1] <= max) {
                li.Add(new List<int>() { f[i][0], b[j][0], f[i][1] + b[j][1] });
                if (m < f[i][1] + b[j][1]) {
                    m = f[i][1] + b[j][1];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return li.Where(i => i[2] == m).ToList();
}
```

Can anyone help me to make it more efficient in terms of time complexity, please?

Comment: Try as i might, I can't understand your problem definition

Comment: You should ask your question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, it seems more appropriate.

Comment: @GonenI can you check it now?

Comment: Are you looking for a completely new code or do you want to modify this one?

Comment: @0009laH either way is fine if you can make it more efficient in terms of time complexity.

Comment: _"return **the** route which uses the maximum travel distance."_ vs _"Result must be: [4,1] **and** [5,2]"_ . So it's actually "return _all_ routes that ..." right?

Comment: Must different inputs be taken into account that could contain duplicate weights?

Comment: Could you please edit your topic to further specify the problem with your code? It really isnt clear what you want, better performance from your code?

Comment: @RenéCarannante _"make it more efficient in terms of time complexity"_ - it's in the question.

Comment: @Fildor please check it now

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can give you a solution draft:

- Let's name the "forward" list `fwList`, the "backward" list `bwList`. Each element contains a **key** and a **value**, in that order.
- Sort both lists in the ascending order using merge sort or heap sort on the **value** part of the elements (**O(N.ln(N))** time complexity).
- For each element of `bwList` (we call it `bwElem`), find the index in `fwList` (we call it `ID`) where the sum is becoming too long (`bwElem + fwList[ID] > 11000`). Then `[bwElem.key, fwList[ID - 1].key]` is part of your solution.
- The concatenation of the results for each element of `bwList` should make your list and, if all is clear in my mind, you should have a **O(bwLength * (fwLength)^a)** time complexity, where **a < 1** (I'd even bet on **O(bwLength * ln(fwLength))**).

I think the algorithm can be optimized using this basis.